# AngularJS app.controller syntax error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am applying code to my project run by this guy https://github.com/simpulton/angular-photo-slider/blob/master/js/app.js. He has a little syntax error already, and the console tells you about it, but after I fixed it the console just gives the vague "SyntaxError: syntax error" message. Here's what I've been trying to do:

```
var app = angular.module('LOC Search', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('locListCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $http)) {
$http.jsonp('http://loc.gov/pictures/collections?fo=json&callback=process=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data) {

$scope.slides = data.collections;

}
}]);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Also, different version of AngularJS will produce different results... Not sure which one to use with this particular example. THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double parentheses at places and some are missing.

Try this:

```
var app = angular.module('LOC Search', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('locListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.jsonp('http://loc.gov/pictures/collections?fo=json&callback=process=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data) {

        $scope.slides = data.collections;

    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to inject the `$http` service.

try:

```
app.controller('locListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
   ...
```

or you can also do:

```
app.controller('locListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    ...
```

but the second one is much less recommended, because the code won't work if you minify the code.